# Opengl какие существуют эффективные способы отрисовки?

Tags: c++, opengl

Есть множество различных мешей(~5000). Все они отрисовываются одним шейдером, всегда в одном и том же положении(model матрица неизменна). В каждом меше около 1000 вершин.

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(...);
glBindVertexArray(...);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ...);
```

И эти 3 строчки повторяются 5000 раз. `glUniformMatrix4fv` можно убрать, но время теряется на `glDrawElements`.

Можно объединить все меши в 1, но даст ли это ощутимый эффект? Причём его надо будет постоянно переделывать, так как меши надо периодически удалять/добавлять новые.
Ещё проблема в том, что для создания теней надо отрисовать ещё 3 раза 5000 мешей.

Что можно сделать для ускорения отрисовки множества различных мешей?

Comment: гугли instancing.

Comment: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing

Comment: Меши различны. Как мне тут поможет инстансинг?